# Decrypting function in java is not working for 3DES

Tags: java, cryptography, 3des

I'm trying to understand if a custom criptography library is working fine or not.

The library is using 3DES and for crypting text I think is working fine because the constructor is generating automatically the key once is run:

```
this.key = this.skf.generateSecret(this.ks);
```

and the encryption scheme is 'DESede'

but my concern is on decrypt because the jar is supposing to receive the crypted text from a DLL and the used key also, but if I look into the code, I think it cannot work because of the wrong key used... a new one by the constructor!

```
public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
String decryptedText = null;
try
{
  this.cipher.init(2, this.key);
  byte[] encryptedText = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString);
  byte[] plainText = this.cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
  decryptedText = new String(plainText);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Logger.getLogger(AgentBrideProtocol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception " + ex);
  Logger.getLogger(AgentBrideProtocol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception " + ex.getMessage());
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
return decryptedText;}
```

how is it possible to work fine?

Answer (score 0):

If the wrong key is used then the text will not decrypt, or at least not decrypt correctly. And yes, if you generate a new key, it will be random and therefore it will be the wrong key with a very high level of certainty.

However, the fact that a new key is used is not apparent from the *horrible* code fragment in your question. It uses `this.key` and we don't know when and how that key is created. If it was created using `SecretKeyFactory#generateSecret` then it will probably throw a `BadPaddingException` or, once in about 256 times for PKCS#7 padding, return a random plaintext.

If you just copied that code from a sample you should *stop right here* and learn about cryptography first. It's **not fine** and if it is part of a library then that library needs to be taken down.